# Taxes defaulting to a particular setting in CartThrob

Tags: cartthrob

We've just come across a strange issue in CartThrob (v2.3.5; EE 2.5.5) where the tax is calculating, but only somewhat.

We've got several different tax rates setup for two states: NY and CA. When using a NY zip code, the tax calculates correctly every time. For CA though, it **always** uses the first tax rate listed and ignores the others, regardless of zip code.

Here's a screenshot of that part of CartThrob: http://cl.ly/RpCc

With that set up, if I use 93657, whose tax rate is 8.975, it still gets calculated as 10% (the first CA tax rate). If I move the first listed CA tax rate of 10% to the bottom, and try to use 93657 again, it then defaults to 9.5% (the new first listed CA tax rate).

I have no idea what could be causing this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Got a fix from CT support on this...

Answer (score 1):

I remember this happening to us, try setting the state to blank instead of "California" so that just the zip codes are used in calculating the values.

We only used the state value if there was one flat rate for the entire state.

Comment: Thanks. We ended up getting support from the CT guys who gave us a fix.